# How to avoid AngularJS directives code showing up on page loading

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a page implemented using AngularJS. When I access the page using FireFox, for a couple of seconds, it shows up some angular directives, but when I use Chrome, it doesn't:
[Using Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC22K.png)

How can I handle it? Is it due to net latency?

Comment: We need code in order to help you.  What behavior do you want?  The FireFox behavior or the Chrome behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'ng-cloak' on the parent tag (preferably in the ng-controller tag) to suppress it. Take a look at the documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Thank you. We fixed our AngularJS legacy apps using ng-cloak.